# Cannot print newline with newline character in a string

Tags: ruby

```
p "\n\n\nRuby Sucks!\n"
```

But, it prints this:

```
"\n\n\nRuby Sucks!\n"
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Ruby doesn't suck, come on.

Comment: @squiguy - maybe a ruby lover gave me -1. I can love it if I get +1 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is using [p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-p), which implicitly calls [Object#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Object.html#method-i-inspect) on its argument. Use [puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) and you'll be fine.

```
>> p "\n\n\nRuby Sucks!\n"
"\n\n\nRuby Sucks!\n"
=> "\n\n\nRuby Sucks!\n"
>> puts "\n\n\nRuby Sucks!\n"



Ruby Sucks!
=> nil
```